# Edittext in TableView not displaying pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android

I am having trouble getting EditText to dynamically populate in TableView, this is only happening on non Lollipop Devices in a fragment (In particular an appcompat fragment, i have not tested in a regular framgent).  When the same code is run in an activity it works fine.

Here is my fragment code on creating the row of edit texts.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daily_field_report, container, false);
    tableLayout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.equipmentLayout);
    context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
    this.inflater = inflater;
    activityContext = getActivity();

    return view;
}

 private void createRow(Equipment equipment, final int editId) {

    TableRow row = new TableRow(context);


    EditText equipmentName = (EditText) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_text_edittext, row, false);
    EditText headerQty = (EditText) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_number_edittext, row, false);
    EditText headerHrs = (EditText) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_number_edittext, row, false);

    equipmentName.setText(equipment.title);
    if (equipment.Qty != 0) {
        headerQty.setText(Integer.toString(equipment.Qty));
    }
    if (equipment.Hrs != 0) {
        headerHrs.setText(Integer.toString(equipment.Hrs));
    }

    equipmentName.setId(editId);

    this.fields.add(equipmentName);
    this.fields.add(headerQty);
    this.fields.add(headerHrs);

    row.addView(equipmentName);
    row.addView(headerQty);
    row.addView(headerHrs);

    tableLayout.addView(row);
    rows.add(new myTableRow(equipment, equipmentName, headerHrs, headerQty));
}
```

And Here are the edit text Xml layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:padding="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="text"
android:ems="10"
android:id="@+id/pumptruckQty"
android:layout_column="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the issue.  When creating the TableRow to add to the TableLayout i was using the wrong context.  The context used to create the Row should be the context of the LayoutInflater that is given in the onCreateView of the fragment.